# Fails to transfer data higher than 16K bytes over USB2.0 using usb_control_msg() function in Linux

Tags: c, linux, usb

I have tried to send 64K Bytes data over USB2.0 and USB3.0 using usb_control_msg() function which is used in usbtest driver.

I can send that amount of data successfully without any issue over USB3.0 but fails to send over USB2.0.

One more thing that i can send upto 16K Bytes data over USB2.0 using that function.

Over USB2.0 it gives error 74 (Bad Message) in ioctl call while using that usb_control_msg() through testusb application for kernel 3.2.

So, Is there any limitation in USB2.0 to send limited amount of data through usb control function?

Comment: Dunno - you could look up the specs?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got from net that USB2.0 can transfer upto 16K Bytes data at a time.